# How does the CSS maze hack work?

Tags: css

The maze is at: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/amazing.html. Just curious how this (and his other demos on cssplay and [elsewhere](http://www.stunicholls.myby.co.uk/index.html)) works - what the core CSS "tricks" are here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work through using the CSS `:hover` pseudoclass.  As you mouse over different segments of the maze, the player piece is either rendered (for valid locations), or a game over is rendered for invalid locations.

Note, for example, that you can start near the end of the maze; the CSS doesn't actually validate your movement, just your current location.

Comment: Isn't there more to it than that? You can't just move anywhere; there's some notion of where you were moving from/to. Only adjacent cells with no dividing wall are allowed to be traversed.

Comment: Actually, the way it works is that when you mouse over a wall, the wall displays the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Open in any major browser (including IE9) and use the inspection tools to find out. Hint: it's all to do with dynamic behaviour on hover.